# In Keystone 6, can we disable the user authentication/user login?

Tags: keystonejs, keystonejs6

It looks like there was a somewhat straightforward way to disable in in Keystone 5 via -
https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone-5/blob/main/docs/guides/authentication.md

But I can't seem to find any resources/direction for Keystone 6.  Any guidance from the community on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it working for my needs.  In the `keystone.js` file, replace

```
export default withAuth(
```

with

```
export default config(
```

and disable the imports for both withAuth and sessions

```
// import { withAuth, session } from './auth';
```

also don't forget to remove `session` from the config export and the trailing `)` at the end.

Comment: Yes, auth isn't part of the core Keystone 6 packages. The `withAuth` function comes from the `@keystone-6/auth` package – part of the official monorepo but not required by all apps. Projects that do need auth can either explicitly add the  `auth` package or implement their own auth solution using the core APIs. The auth guide for details: https://keystonejs.com/docs/config/auth